# Ansible Connection Failure: Unknown Type

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am very new to ansible. I am trying to work on prototype to automate cisco routers/switch (Currently trying with Cisco C3600) using virtualbox (host only adapter) connected directly GNS3 emulated cisco router. Virtualbox running Ubuntu server 16.04 installed with Ansible version 2.6.2.cp

I am trying to run some basic show commands and saving it to ubuntu server using playbook but I keep getting Unknown type error. I am able to run the show commands using Ansible ad hoc commands.

```
ansible 192.168.56.111 -m ios_command -a "commands='show version'" -c local -u <u_name> -k
```

Can someone please tell what is wrong in my playbook ?

```
---
- hosts: 192.168.56.111
  gather_facts: true
  connection: local


  tasks:
   - name: run mutiple commands on remote nodes
     ios_command:
       host: 192.168.56.111
       username: *****
       password: *****
       commands: 
         - show version
         - show interfaces

  - name: show run
    ios_command:
      commands:
        - show run
      host: 192.168.56.111
      username: ****
      password: ****
     register: config

 - name: save output to /etc/ansible/playbooks
   copy:
     content: "{{ config.stdout[0] }}"
     dest: "/etc/ansible/playbooks/show_run.txt"
```

Inventory:

```
 # This is the default ansible 'hosts' file.
 #
 # It should live in /etc/ansible/hosts
 #
 #   - Comments begin with the '#' character
 #   - Blank lines are ignored
 #   - Groups of hosts are delimited by [header] elements
 #   - You can enter hostnames or ip addresses
 #   - A hostname/ip can be a member of multiple groups

 # Ex 1: Ungrouped hosts, specify before any group headers.

 ## green.example.com
 ## blue.example.com
 ## 192.168.100.1
 ## 192.168.100.10
 192.168.56.111
```

Error Message:

```
ansible-playbook 2.6.2
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = 
        [u'/home/<username>/.ansible/plugins/modules', 
        u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) [GCC 5.4.0 
  20160609]
  Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
  setting up inventory plugins
 Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
 Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from 
 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.pyc

PLAYBOOK: backup_cisco_router.yaml 
*****************************************************************
1 plays in backup_cisco_router.yaml

PLAY [192.168.56.111] 
********************************************************************          
TASK [Gathering Facts] 
*******************************************************************
 task path: /etc/ansible/playbooks/backup_cisco_router.yaml:2
<192.168.56.111> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<192.168.56.111> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<192.168.56.111> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo 
 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1535722277.58-97501065121445 `" && echo 
 ansible-tmp-1535722277.58-97501065121445="` echo 
/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1535722277.58-97501065121445 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
<192.168.56.111> PUT /home/<username>/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local- 
1860jy6GrC/tmp3KDn_s TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1535722277.58- 
97501065121445/setup.py
<192.168.56.111> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp- 
1535722277.58-97501065121445/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1535722277.58- 
97501065121445/setup.py && sleep 0'
<192.168.56.111> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python 
/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1535722277.58-97501065121445/setup.py && 
sleep 0'
<192.168.56.111> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp- 
1535722277.58-97501065121445/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [192.168.56.111]
META: ran handlers

 TASK [run mutiple commands on remote nodes] 
 ********************************************************
 task path: /etc/ansible/playbooks/backup_cisco_router.yaml:8
<192.168.56.111> using connection plugin network_cli (was local)
<192.168.56.111> starting connection from persistent connection plugin
<192.168.56.111> local domain socket does not exist, starting it
<192.168.56.111> control socket path is 
/home/<username>/.ansible/pc/bbb52332a5
<192.168.56.111> 
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/ansible-connection", line 87, in start
  self.connection._connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/ansible/plugins/connection/network_cli.py", line 298, in _connect
ssh = self.paramiko_conn._connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/ansible/plugins/connection/paramiko_ssh.py", line 249, in _connect
self.ssh = SSH_CONNECTION_CACHE[cache_key] = self._connect_uncached()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/ansible/plugins/connection/paramiko_ssh.py", line 365, in 
     _connect_uncached
  raise AnsibleConnectionFailure(msg)
 AnsibleConnectionFailure: Unknown type
 fatal: [192.168.56.111]: FAILED! => {
      "msg": "Unknown type"
   }
 to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/playbooks/backup_cisco_router.retry

  PLAY RECAP 
  ***********************************************************
 192.168.56.111             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with network modules and modules connection but reading https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/network/getting_started/first_playbook.html#run-your-first-network-ansible-command I'm not sure you using the correct `connection` method, you should use `network_cli`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the hostname, username and password from the playbook and put it in your inventory file.

```
[all:vars]
ansible_connection=local
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python
#ansible_ssh_common_args='-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null'
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o UserKnownHostsFile=~/.ssh/known_hosts'
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
ansible_ssh_user=ciscoadmin
ansible_ssh_pass=CiScO123
device_type=cisco_ios

[learn]
192.168.56.111
```

Next, correct your host statement in the playbook.

Change

```
hosts: 192.168.56.11
```

to

```
hosts: learning
```

Everything else looks pretty good. If you still get errors, make sure you can SSH to the router from the host. Also run ansible-playbook with -vvvv for verbose.